# slurm how to get the cpu_ids from within an sbatch job?

Tags: slurm

What's the best way to get the valid cpu ids from within a running job? 
My idea is to do an allocation --> wrap a docker command with the limits of the allocation --> run `nvidia-docker` on an remote gpu server.

To limit the docker to the allocation I need to tell it the `cpu_ids`.

My job submission will look like:

```
sbatch -o test.txt -c2 -n 10 --mem=10GB --wrap="job that needs the cpu_ids"
```

Answer (score 2):

In the script you launch with sbatch, you should execute the next line in order to get the CPU IDs and save them in a file:

```
scontrol -dd show job $SLURM_JOB_ID | grep "CPU_IDs" | sed 's/^ *//' > cpuids.out
```